# Calculus Residue

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How to get the following result

```
Table[Residue[Pi F[z] Sec[Pi z], {z, 2k + 1/2}], {k, -1, 1}]
```

> {-F[-(3/2)], -F[1/2], -F[5/2]}

but it is posible to get the general term of the series directly as result as F[(1 + 4 k)/2] directly not to calculate by hand.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Without additional information on F[z] this question is not answerable...

Comment: Why not just seeking residues of Sec[Pi z] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include an assumption in your [`Residue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Residue) call:

```
Residue[π F[z] Sec[π z], {z, 2 k + 1/2}, Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]
```

> -F[1/2 + 2 k] Sec[2 k π]

*Addressing OP comment*

To eliminate the unwanted $\sec (2 k \pi)$ terms, use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify). One way (besides the one provided by @JoseAntonioDiazNavas) is to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming):

```
Assuming[k ∈ Integers, Simplify @ Residue[π F[z] Sec[π z], {z, 2 k + 1/2}]]
```

> -F[1/2 + 2 k]

Comment: thanks Carl , how i could to paste mma code not latex

Comment: Carl how to get a result  directly F[1/2+2 k]  eliminate automatically the trivial result as Sec[2k Pi]==1 thanks

Comment: What if F has a singularity there, e.g., F[z]=Sec[Pi z] ? The question is not well posed, so MAs answer is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Following Carl, closer to what is requested:

```
Simplify[Residue[\[Pi] F[z] Sec[\[Pi] z], {z, 1/2(4k + 1)}, Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers],  
Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers]

(* -F[1/2 + 2 k] *)
```

Comment: Thanks Jose Antonio Diaz

Comment: So vote up !!  It is the best way to acknowledge help.